# Dizzel Prompting socket error #11002 when launched?

Tags: steam, technical-issues

i just downloaded Dizzel on Steam (Free Game), and tried to launch it , first it downloaded a couple of updates, then when i ran the game there was an error saying "socket error #11002" while trying to connect to the server , any one know how can i fix this?